# Regular Expressions in js .replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm very new to regular expressions and need to strip out some commas.  I'm trying to turn Fri,,April,6,,2012 
into 
Fri, April 6, 2012.

Any ideas?
My current code follows.  eDate is Fri,,April,6,,2012

```
eDate = edDate4.replace(/,+/g, ", ").replace(/^,/, "").replace(/,$/, "").split(",");
```

It returns Fri, April, 6, 2012.

Thanks Juan for your help!
When I changed it to

```
eDate = edDate4.replace(",,", ", ").replace(",,", ", ");
```

I got Fri, April,6, 2012

Thanks so much.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: The problem is that I need it to take off the second comma and add a space and add a space after 6,
which it's not doing.

Comment: where are you getting the badly formatted date in the first place? maybe that should be where your change occurs, not after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

`.replace(/,{2,}/g, ", ").replace(/,(?! )/g, " ")`

In your certain example you may do even simpler `.replace(/,(?!,)/g, " ")`, but it will replace `",,,"` into `",, "`, not `",  "`

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a strange way round it but i would replace all comma's with a space, then anywhere that has two spaces replace with a comma. A bit like so

```
var edDate4 = "Fri,,April,6,,2012"​;
var eDate = edDate4.replace(/,/g, " ")​​​​​​​​.replace(/\s\s/g, ", ");
alert(eDate) //Gives "Fri, April 6, 2012"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

````js
var stringWithoutComments = s.replace(/(`[^*]*`)|(```[^*]*```)|(''[^*]*'')|(<div [^*]*div>)|(,)|(<[^*]*>)/g, ' ');
console.log(stringWithoutComments);
````